# Using XQuery in SQL 2005 to replace a node's value?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql, xquery

Given the following XML variable, how can I replace "**UNKNOWN**" in the *StateCode* node with "**FOO**" in TSQL for MS SQL 2005?

```
declare @xmldata xml

set @xmldata = 

    '<Collection>
        <Plan>
            <StateCode>UNKNOWN</StateCode>
            <Type>Tubular</Type> 
        </Plan>
    </Collection>'
```

Unlike a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276009/using-xquery-modify-to-replace-a-piece-of-my-xml-with-value-from-varchar-field) that I found, this is simply an XML typed variable, not a table record.

Should I simply insert the variable value into a table and go with the method presented in that question, or can I just manipulate the XML variable directly and perform the replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the XML variable directly and perform the replacement:

```
set @xmldata.modify('replace value of (/Collection/Plan/Type/text())[1] with "new value"')

select @xml
```

(The XPath might not be exactly correct as I don't have access to a sql server atm)

Also, note that this won't work if UNKNOWN is actually empty text, that requires a bit more work!)

Comment: what is the workaround in the edge case you mention (empty text)